# competitors for asp.net membership?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

What are the competitors for the standard ASP.NET login web controls?
I want to build a scalable site and manage the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, there is [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) which is a big time opensource user/login/permissions, CMS all free and works in .net with sql server.  Also you can go to visual studio and start a new project and as long as you don't choose the empty project it will create a mini project with a login system that you have to add your database info and so on.

Then again if you're starting out there's nothing like learning and doing it yourself, its fairly simple.

1. sql server table with username, password, accesstype(admin, user)
2. login form with username, password fields
3. do a select to table passing username and passwords and see if it returns a value, if not the combo incorrect.
4. if it doesn't start session and set the user id in session if you need to use it somewhere else or just to make sure that it times out by checking that session id in everypage.

that's reallyyy basic but its the idea of it.